# CMB Metabox and Select Dropdown

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes

i am having problem with CMB metabox and  select dropdown. I can see only first letter of value for example if my select box have in array Banana, Orange, Apple it prints only first letter both in admin and website (frontend). What can cause that problem?

```
        array(
'name'    => 'Test Radio',
'id'      => $prefix . 'test_radio',
'type'    => 'radio',
'options' => array(
    'standard' => __( 'Banana', 'cmb' ),
    'custom'   => __( 'Orange', 'cmb' ),
    'none'     => __( 'Apple', 'cmb' ),
),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. This works for me :

```
array(
    'name'    => 'Test Select',
    'id'      => $prefix . 'test_select',
    'type'    => 'select',
    'options' => array(
        array(
            'name'  => __( 'Banana', 'cmb' ),
            'value' => 'banana',
        ),
        array(
            'name'  => __( 'Orange', 'cmb' ),
            'value' => 'orange',
        ),
        array(
            'name'  => __( 'Apple', 'cmb' ),
            'value' => 'apple',
        ),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a radio type field and need the select type field.  Try this:

```
array(
'name'    => 'Test Select',
'id'      => $prefix . 'test_select',
'type'    => 'select',
'options' => array(
    'banana'    => __( 'Banana', 'cmb' ),
    'orange'    => __( 'Orange', 'cmb' ),
    'apple'     => __( 'Apple', 'cmb' ),
    ),
),
```